Issue with JSON Extraction: GPT-3.5 Turbo vs. GPT-4 o-Mini Module
I'm facing a challenge with extracting JSON data from files using different AI models and could use some help.
Problem Description:
When I provide file content to ChatGPT 3.5 Turbo, I receive a complete JSON output. However, when using the GPT-4 o-Mini module via the external OpenAI API, which has a higher input token limit of 8192, I’m not getting the full JSON data.
Details:
Models: GPT-3.5 Turbo vs. GPT-4 o-Mini
Input Tokens Limit: 8192 (GPT-4 o-Mini) vs. a lesser limit for GPT-3.5 Turbo
Issue: Despite the higher token limit of GPT-4 o-Mini, I'm receiving incomplete JSON data from it, whereas GPT-3.5 Turbo provides the full output.
Steps Taken:
Provided file content to GPT-3.5 Turbo – received the full JSON output.
Used the external OpenAI API with GPT-4 o-Mini – resulted in incomplete JSON data.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with token limits affecting the completeness of data extraction? What are some best practices for ensuring complete JSON extraction with models like GPT-4 o-Mini, especially when handling larger inputs?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It's unclear in the question whether your response is incomplete in the sense that :

It is cut after N characters and the JSON is totally invalid, or
It contains a valid JSON, but it's missing some data you expected

... so I might be missing the point, but some generic ideas below:
Ensure the max_tokens parameter is not set too low for the response
You mentioned accessing GPT-4o-mini with an external API (I guess this differs from how you access ChatGPT-3.5-turbo).
If you are using some library to perform the query, you might want to make sure that it doesn't set the max-tokens parameter to a value that's too low for your use case.
Some libraries default to a maximum of 1000 output tokens or similar unless you explicitly set it to a higher number.
Fit more data within input/output limits by removing JSON indentation
If the data seems to slightly exceed the limits for input/output, you can sometimes mitigate it by removing the unnecessary JSON indentation and, therefore, reducing the number of tokens (sometimes by 50% or more).
